# Three full length columns in html

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.leftcolumn {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: brown;
}

.middlecolumn {
  float: left;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div>
        test1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middlecolumn">
      test2
  </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to make three columns next to each other whilst being 100% in height.

I think the problem is that I used 'float: left;', but I wouldn't know what I should've needed to use.

Answer (score 1):

Since both left and middle columns are `div`, it will be by default `display: block`, you need to override it to `display: inline-block` to adjust in the same row.

Other than that the columns are taking 100% height, I have tried giving 100vh to the body, so it is working as expected.

```css
body {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  height: 100vh;
}
.leftcolumn, .middlecolumn {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.leftcolumn {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: brown;
}

.middlecolumn {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div>
        test1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middlecolumn">
      test2
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you should use `min-height` instead to prevent overflow issues. Alos not, that without bod margin reset you will "overflow" by default.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the columns are not the full height is because you are using **height: 100%** on the columns

This inherits the full height of the parent element which is the body in this case, to simply fix this, add a height to your body like so:

```
body {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

The **Margin: 0** is there to not make the page overflow

Comment: you should use `min-height` instead to prevent overflow issues. Alos not, that without bod margin reset you will "overflow" by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have to add height to html, body.
can u please use this code in css, it will work.

body,html{height:100%};